# How to write the xpath for span tag

Tags: xpath

```
<span class="autoSuggKeywords">
samsung
refrigerator
</span>
```

i want to access the content refrigerator using xpath 
objective :identify the element using Autosuggestion

i tried below

```
.//span[@class="autoSuggKeywords"]


.//[text()='refrigerator']
```

Comment: <span class="autoSuggKeywords">
<b>samsung</b>
<b>refrigerator</b>
</span>

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution :

```
//span[contains(@class, 'autoSuggKeywords') and text() = 'refrigerator']
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**xpath** expression:

```
//span[@class="autoSuggKeywords" and contains(.,'refrigerator')]
```